# ADSL connection issue

Tags: linux, adsl-router

I have a problem with the ADLS internet connection: when the first pc is connected, everything is ok and the browsing speed is about 4 mbps per second without lost packets, when the second pc connects to the internet via wifi, the internet connection and the adsl carrier of the d-link router falls and there are 10% to 40% of lost packets when I ping google servers. The internet connection is managed by the d-link router so what can it depend on?

Comment: Your post is not clear. Is the packet loss experienced on both computers simultaneously? Is this ISP equipment? Have you spoken with your ISP? Please [edit] your post to improve it.

Comment: Yes, the packets are loss on both computers simultaneously. Is it a routing issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "ADSL carrier falls"? What model router do you have? It could (but is very unlikely to be) interference on the ADSL line. I postulate that the line is OK, but some software running on the second computer is generating a lot of traffic and taking out the connection. A 4megabit ADSL connection would be marginal, and the upload speed is probably a fraction of this and being saturated.

Comment: But the first PC with similar hardware, the same operating system, the same updates, the same kernel, and the same software does not cause a connection failure, how come?